# compare terms from userterm and node term

Tags: theming, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have users and nodes.
bith have the same term referende field:

field_area

goal is to display a message in node.tpl.php when:
- user has term 'south'
- node has term 'south'

i have used the field extract module to get id term ID from the node.
$tid_node = field_extract_value('node', $node, 'field_bedrijf', 0, array('key' => 'tid'));
term id is .e.g: 5

Now i would like to find the term id using the user->field_area field.

I would utlimately have a code like:

```
if $tid_node == $tid_user {
print "a custom message" ;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after seaching around. 
node term id:

```
$node_tid = field_extract_value('node', $node, 'field_your_taxonomy_reference_field', 0, array('key' => 'tid'));
```

user term id:

```
//load current user    
$user_info = user_load($user->uid);
$user_term_id = $user_your_taxonomy_reference_field['und'][0]['tid'];
```

now set logic
    if  ($node_tid == $user_term_id) {
    print "show link";
     }